# Is there a correct location to place favicon / icon files in my web root?

Tags: .htaccess, favicon

I've recently worked on improvements on a website made by someone else.

One thing I notices the webroot was polluted by lots of favicon/apple touch icons file of many dimensions.

Is there a practical reason to maintain those files in there?

Maybe some SEO reason ? Or maybe because some browser/devices automatically try to load e.g. /favicon.ico  ?
(In the second case could be solved e.g. under Apache with a .htaccess redirect rule)

Wouldn't it be more practical to place them inside a folder like 
/img/icons/...

Having the web root files with 10-20 favicon files looks very dirty solution to me.

(A secondary question would be is it really necessary to produce all dimension version of the favicon for various device (favicon16x16.ico, favicon32x32.ico, favicon48x48.ico....)? is there around a cleaner solution?)

Comment: There is no real practical reason for putting all these files in the root. It is likely they have just thrown them in and coded it to the root. So ideally, it should be like you suggest `/img/icons/...` - if you decide to change this just be wary of how they've coded everything, these will need to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Answering the secondary question:

*Multiple favicon variants.*

Storing multiple favicon variants is often done for performance reasons, and to support really old browsers. You can put multiple variations of your icon in a single file, but that would mean that a user has to download all your variations when accessing your page. This can result in high server load and a website that loads more slowly. Every millisecond counts, so having separate files makes a lot of sense.